# How to set the "realm" using PHP OAuth?

Tags: php, oauth

I have the following:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
$oauth->setToken($oauth_access_token,$oauth_access_token_secret);
```

When I then execute:

```
$h = $oauth->getRequestHeader(OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $url);
```

I get the header:

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_nonce="1454566103",oauth_timestamp="1454566103",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="XXXXXXX",oauth_signature="XXXXXXXXXX"
```

The problem is, I am expecting this:

```
OAuth realm="1111", oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_nonce="1454566103",oauth_timestamp="1454566103",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="XXXXXXX",oauth_signature="XXXXXXXXXX"
```

But it's not obvious how to add the "realm" part. How do I add the realm, so that when the signature is generated, it accounts for the realm in the initial build string?

Comment: I found your post really interesting, and researching a little about your issue I came accross this [post](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/issues/424), it may be useful for you :)

Comment: If you're using the library from [pecl.php.net](https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth) documented in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) I don't think it supports this. Certainly the word "realm" doesn't appear anywhere in the source code, the documentation, or the examples. You might have to download another library from the list at http://oauth.net/code/.

Comment: It actually supports any extra parameters you want to pass into it

Answer (score 0):

Try making it:

```
$h = $oauth->getRequestHeader(OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $url,'realm=1234').',realm="1234"';
```

Answer (score -1):

I may be totally wrong, but can we set the headers by using htaccess in the desired directory ?
By this way, your expected headers will be included in every request , if thats not a problem

Something like this in your case ...

```
Header add realm "1111"
```

Comment: Its got to go into the signature generation function